# Sourcetree 3.3.6 Refresh issue

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

Sourcetree 3.3.6 with windows 10 not updating UI contents or not refreshing views.
If you want to see updated view then you need to restart app.
any solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pressing F5 after fetching, making edits, etc. to refresh updates the UI.  Annoying, but usable until fixed.

Comment: It's caused at least 3 branch merges for no reason and is messing up my tree. My workflow is 1) commit (success) + push (error), 2) swear loudly, 3) pull, 4) push the merge.

Answer (score 1):

seems to be related to bookmarks. deleting it solves it, at least for me.
found it here: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Manual-refresh-required/qaq-p/1256362

how to delete bookmarks can be found here:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/bookmarks-column-repository-browser-overview-781398414.html